# How to use Django's inbuilt authentication with custom forms (html templates)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-authentication

I am trying to create a website using Django where user can register and login  currently I am storing the user registration data in my custom database table.

But I am not finding any sold way to do user authentication using the data from my custom tables

So I am in search of a way where I can use Django's inbuilt user auth but with my custom forms( html templates) on top

Please Help me !!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use django-allauth package. What you want has been implemented already.
You can follow the documentation below https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html